# LongestFlowpath error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, error, hec-geohms

I get this error every time I try to get the longest flowpath. It says  that the spatial reference is not set for the input(s), yet all layers in my table of contents are set in the same spatial reference which is WGS_84_UTM_zone_51N.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures.  That way they are available to future searches by people seeing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1. Are you sure that the underlying input data sets have a spatial reference defined, and not just the ArcMap data frame that you are viewing them in? Check the properties of the source data in ArcCatalog.
2. Is there a feature dataset inside of your geodatabase? (From the path listed in the error message it looks like there might be.) I would suggest staying away from that. Just keep your data in the top level of the GDB. It's tempting to use feature datasets as if they were folders, to organize things, but they can be a little quirky, specifically about spatial references.